# How to assign each box of a grid an iD

Tags: java, processing

I have this code to create a grid and to fill the box of the grid when the mouse is on it:

```
int cols = 10, rows = 10;
boolean[][] states = new boolean[cols][rows];
int videoScale = 50;

void setup(){
  size(500,500);

}
void draw(){
  // Begin loop for columns
  for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    // Begin loop for rows
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {

      // Scaling up to draw a rectangle at (x,y)
      int x = i*videoScale;
      int y = j*videoScale;

      fill(255);
      stroke(0);
      //check if coordinates are within a box (these are mouse x,y but could be fiducial x,y)
      //simply look for bounds (left,right,top,bottom)
      if( (mouseX >= x &&  mouseX <= x + videoScale) && //check horzontal
          (mouseY >= y &&  mouseY <= y + videoScale)){
        //coordinates are within a box, do something about it
        fill(0);
        stroke(255);
        //you can keep track of the boxes states (contains x,y or not) 
        states[i][j] = true;

        if(mousePressed) println(i+"/"+j);

      }else{

        states[i][j] = false;

      }


      rect(x,y,videoScale,videoScale); 
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to assign each box an iD like A2, B7, etc and then to have printed in the console the iD of the box the mouse is on.

Could someone please help me do this ? I have no idea about how to define a precise area and to give it an ID

Comment: Please only ask a concrete quesiton. Which part is not working? What is it doing that is incorrect? What do you expect? What have you tried? What happened when you debugged? Did you try logging statements? Etc.

Comment: Some variation of (sorry Python not Java): `chr(ord('A') + (num % 26)` for 0 to 25. To get the second letter, you can do `num // 26` (integer devision) and then do a similar conversion to a letter.

Comment: @Kon The code in my post works, but does not have an ID attached to each box. I can't find anywhere on google how to assign an iD to an area of the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast integer to char using ASCII (table here: http://www.asciitable.com/).

```
String[][] coordinates = new String[cols][rows]; 

for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) { 

coordinates[i][j] = String.valueOf((char)(i+65)) + String.valueOf(j).toUpperCase();

  }
}
```

When moused over:

```
System.out.println(coordinates[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the box coordinates of the mouse in `i` and `j`. Just convert these to an ID using something like:

```
String id = Character.toString((char)('A' + i)) + (1 + j);
```

You could also use an array look-up for the first part of the ID.